# XMLinvalid in Design Layout Update

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml

XML is invalid when doing Magento Design Layout Update xml with following code

```
<reference name=”content”>
    <block type=”catalog/product_new” template=”catalog/product/new.phtml”>
        <action method=”setProductsCount”><count>9</count></action>
        <action method=”addColumnCountLayoutDepend”><layout>empty</layout><count>5</count></action>
        <action method=”addColumnCountLayoutDepend”><layout>one_column</layout><count>4</count></action>
        <action method=”addColumnCountLayoutDepend”><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>3</count></action>
        <action method=”addColumnCountLayoutDepend”><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>3</count></action>
        <action method=”addColumnCountLayoutDepend”><layout>three_columns</layout><count>2</count></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you should use a validator to validate your XML. This can be any tool depending on what OS you are using. You can also use something like this: https://www.google.com/#q=validate+xml+online

What I see is that you are using a really weird double quote in there. Use normal quotes:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml">
        <action method="setProductsCount"><count>9</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>5</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>4</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>3</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>3</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>2</count></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

When I try to validate the above with normal quotes, then it seems just fine.

Comment: thanks it worked out after chaging the quote, I am new to magento can you help me changing the content of the page

Comment: Changing the content of the page is a different question. Please post a new question for this